# EF 5 Code First using Inheritence in the class

Tags: entity-framework

I am getting Error when trying to run this code.

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'AddressBook.DAL.Models.User' and 'AddressBook.DAL.Models.User'.
>   The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured
>   using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

The objective is that i am creating baseClass that has commonfield for all the tables.

IF i don't use base class everything works fine.

```
namespace AddressBook.DAL.Models
{
public class BaseTable
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateLastUpdatedOn { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual int CreatedByUserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedByUserId")]
    public virtual User CreatedByUser { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual int UpdatedByUserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UpdatedByUserId")]
    public virtual User UpdatedByUser { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public RowStatus RowStatus { get; set; }

}

public enum RowStatus
{
    NewlyCreated,
    Modified,
    Deleted
}


}




namespace AddressBook.DAL.Models
{
public class User : BaseTable
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

}

}
```

Comment: I've done this in EF4, and the only difference with your code was that I didn't put the virtual keyword on the int key properties. Maybe try with `public int CreatedByUserId {get;set;}` and `public int UpdatedByUserId {get;set;}` ??

Comment: I don't know if i am the only one but i don't understand your error. `AddressBook.DAL.Models.User and AddressBook.DAL.Models.User` (Same Models?). Also, you mentioned the use of `Inheritence` and yet, there is no sign of such in the code provided.

Comment: @Komenge Mwandila There is a `1..1` relationship from users to users because a user can be modified/created by another user or himself.

Also, you can see that User inherits BaseTable `public class User : BaseTable { ...`

Comment: @matthew.perron sorry i missed the `User Class`. Neglected to scroll down

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide mapping information to EF. The following article describes code-first strategies for different EF entity inheritance models (table-per-type, table-per-hierarchy, etc.). Not all the scenarios are directly what you are doing here, but pay attention to the mapping code because that's what you need to consider (and it's good info in case you want to use inheritance for other scenarios). Note that inheritance does have limitations and costs when it comes to ORMs, particularly with polymorphic associations (which makes the TPC scenario somewhat difficult to manage). http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx

The other way EF can handle this kind of scenario is by aggregating a complex type into a "fake" compositional relationship. In other words, even though your audit fields are part of some transactional entity table, you can split them out into a common complex type which can be associated to any other entity that contains those same fields. The difference here is that you'd actually be encapsulting those fields into another type. So for example, if you moved your audit fields into an "Audit" complext type, you would have something like:
User.Audit.DateCreated
instead of
User.DateCreated

In any case, you still need to provide the appropriate mapping information.
This article here explains how to do this: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/11/entity-association-mapping-with-code-first-part-1-one-to-one-associations.aspx

Comment: He uses DataAnnotation to represent the mapping relationship information. You can see it in the `BaseTable` class where the FK are defined: `[ForeignKey("CreatedByUserId")]`.